# How to avoid repeating URL structures in Django

Tags: html, django, url, django-templates, dry

The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) explains how to create a basic poll app. The templates in the tutorial frequently use hard-coded URL structures—for instance:

```
<form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/" method="post">
```

And:

```
<a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">Vote again?</a>
```

What would be the best way to refactor this code to avoid repeating `/polls/` throughout the templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `url` template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, name your urls.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

In the template, the url would look like:

`<a href="{% url poll_url poll.id %}">Vote again?</a>`

In the view, the url can be retrieved using the `reverse` method like:

`reverse('poll_url', args=[poll.id])`